# Why this collection is returning this error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

can someone please show where is the error ?

```
$material = DB::table('material_user')->where('material_user.id', $id)
                     ->leftjoin('users', 'users.id','=','material_user.user_id')
                     ->leftjoin('materials', 'materials.id','=','material_user.material_id')
                     ->select('users.first_name','users.last_name','users.sexe','materials.serial','materials.name','material_user.created_at')
                     ->get();
dd($material->first_name);
```

Exception
Property [first_name] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: `$material` is a collection of `material_user`, not a single row. If you're expecting a single row, use `first()` instead of `get()`

Comment: i am feeling dumb thx bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get()` returns a **collection**. So you have to iterate over the collection to get the `first_name` for e.g

```
foreach ($material as $object)
    echo $object->first_name;
endforeach
```

Or you can get the single record using below & can access first_name directly

```
$object =  $material->first();
echo $object->first_name
```